# How to print out the whole article on the web that uses the scroll from left to right feature by clicking on the arrow buttons

Tags: printing, printing-web-page

when I come across these types of articles and simply want to print the full article out without using the left to right scroll buttons. How can this be done?

Did not know what to try or even how to approach accomplishing this task.